# how to put a image as a background in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

How to add background image to panel1? Which command is there?

Code:

```
import wx
import wx
appy=wx.App()

class cg(wx.Frame) :
     def __init__(self,parent,id) :
         wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'GPA',pos=(1000,600),size=(600,400))
         #splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
         panel1 = wx.Panel(self)
         panel2 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1,size=(600,200),style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
         panel3 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1,pos=(0,200),size=(600,200),style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
         #panel3=wx.panel(panel1,-1,pos=(300,200),size=(600,200),style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
         #panel13 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
         #panel13 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
         #panel13 = wx.Panel(panel1, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

         #button1=wx.Button(panel1,label='exit',pos=(10,10),size=(10,10))
         #self.cnt1=wx.TextCtrl(panel1,pos=(40,60),size=(120,30))

if __name__=='__main__' :

     app=wx.PySimpleApp()
     frame=cg(parent=None,id=-1)
     frame.Show()
     app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple search would have brought you to this answer from [The Mouse vs. The Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/).

```
# create a background image on a wxPython panel
# and show a button on top of the image

import wx

class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    """class Panel1 creates a panel with an image on it, inherits wx.Panel"""
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        # create the panel
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        try:
            # pick an image file you have in the working folder
            # you can load .jpg  .png  .bmp  or .gif files
            image_file = 'roses.jpg'
            bmp1 = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
            # image's upper left corner anchors at panel coordinates (0, 0)
            self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp1, (0, 0))
            # show some image details
            str1 = "%s  %dx%d" % (image_file, bmp1.GetWidth(), bmp1.GetHeight()) 
            parent.SetTitle(str1)
        except IOError:
            print "Image file %s not found" % imageFile
            raise SystemExit

        # button goes on the image --> self.bitmap1 is the parent
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.bitmap1, id=-1, label='Button1', pos=(8, 8))

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
# create a window/frame, no parent, -1 is default ID
# change the size of the frame to fit the backgound images
frame1 = wx.Frame(None, -1, "An image on a panel", size=(350, 400))
# create the class instance
panel1 = Panel1(frame1, -1)
frame1.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: can u please tell how to load the jpg image?

Comment: Have you read the code or visited the site? It is explained very clearly: `image_file = 'roses.jpg'`. It looks in the same file as the script is run. If you want to provide a full path, look into `os.path.join`. Would appreciate you selecting this as best-answer too if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 5):

The corrected example from [The Mouse vs. The Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/).

```
import wx
 
########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""
 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_PAINT) # Was wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent
 
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
 
        for num in range(4):
            label = "Button %s" % num
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()
 
        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("butterfly.jpg")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)
 
 
########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""
 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,450))
        panel = MainPanel(self)        
        self.Center()
 
########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""
 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()
 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Setting `self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)` no longer works. That line should be removed or use `self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)` but given that that is the default, best just leave it out.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony: Thanks for bringing this up. Actually, since we are defining an EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND handler this  is now recommended to be BG_STYLE_PAINT, see https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Window.html?highlight=setbackgroundstyle#wx.Window.SetBackgroundStyle

Comment: @SteveBarnes then why does BG_STYLE_PAINT not work and BG_STYLE_ERASE does?

Comment: @VaidøtasI. I don't know I am just going on the documented behaviour.