# wxpython window crashes after event handling

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython, wxwidgets

This code reads a picture and put it as background in a window.
There are two issues I cannot explain:

- once you import the picture, clicking the red "X" in the top-right corner doesn't close the window.
- if you try to drag the image, the program crashes.

Why is it so?
Thank you

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title=title, size=(300, 300))
        self.initUI()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, size=(10000, 10000))
        self.backGroundImage=''
        self.Layout()

    def initUI(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

        imp = wx.Menu()
        importBackgroundButton = imp.Append(wx.ID_ANY, 'Import background')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnImportBackground, importBackgroundButton)
        fileMenu.AppendMenu(wx.ID_ANY, 'I&mport', imp)
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.SetTitle('test')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    #load background
    def OnImportBackground(self, e):
        app = wx.App(None)
        style = wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, 'Open', wildcard='*.png', style=style)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dialog.GetPath()
        else:
            path = None
        dialog.Destroy()
        self.backgroundImage = ButtonImage(self, self.panel, path, (0, 0))
        W = self.backgroundImage.bmp.GetSize()[0]
        H = self.backgroundImage.bmp.GetSize()[1]
        self.SetSize((W+16, H+58))
        self.Refresh()
        #crash


class ButtonImage():
    def __init__(self, parent, panel, nameImage, pos):
        self.panel = panel
        self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(nameImage, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.maxPiecePositionX = self.panel.GetSize()[0] - self.bmp.GetSize()[0]
        self.maxPiecePositionY = self.panel.GetSize()[1] - self.bmp.GetSize()[1]
        self.bmapBtn = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, bitmap=self.bmp, style=wx.NO_BORDER, pos=pos)
        self.bmapBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnClickDown, self.bmapBtn)
        self.bmapBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnClickUp, self.bmapBtn)
        self.bmapBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.MoveButton, self.bmapBtn)
        self.hold = 0
        self.holdPosition = (0, 0)

    def EnterButton(self, event):
        pass

    def LeaveButton(self, event):
        self.hold = 0

    def OnClickDown(self, event):
        obj = event.GetEventObject()
        self.hold = 1
        self.holdPosition = (event.GetX(), event.GetY())

    def OnClickUp(self, event):
        self.hold = 0

    def MoveButton(self, event):
        deltaX, deltaY = 0, 0
        if self.hold:
            deltaX = event.GetPosition()[0] - self.holdPosition[0]
            deltaY = event.GetPosition()[1] - self.holdPosition[1]
            newPositionX = self.bmapBtn.GetPosition()[0] + deltaX
            newPositionY = self.bmapBtn.GetPosition()[1] + deltaY
            if (0 < newPositionX < self.maxPiecePositionX) and (0 < newPositionY < self.maxPiecePositionY):
                self.bmapBtn.SetPosition((newPositionX, newPositionY))
            else:
                self.holdPosition = self.holdPosition[0] + deltaX, self.holdPosition[1] + deltaY
            self.bmapBtn.Raise()
            self.bmapBtn.Refresh()

app = wx.App()
frame = Main(None, "Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: also: try uncommenting the line "  #crash" in the event handler, and dragging the image works.. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example has so many issues  that it would take a long time to explain it. E. g., you create a new `ButtonImage`, which is essentially a `wx.BitmapButton`, every time you call `OnImportBackground` without destroying the old one, stacking up a collection of bitmap buttons without properly layouting them.

But what is driving the nail into the coffin that you instantiate a new `wx.App` every time `OnImportBackground` is called. If you remove this line (which is completely pointless), the frame can at least be closed.

But to see for *"the right way (TM)"* to do it, look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341867/how-to-put-a-image-as-a-background-in-wxpython).

Comment: ahh.. that was it. The instantiations of wx.App! I really missed that. Thanks a lot.
Re the stacking of backgrounds: it's a "feature" :)
I stripped down the code keeping only the essential for a working version for stackoverflow..