# Why my os can't open a new window to show the image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have setted the default application --gimp to open image in my os (debian 11 + lxde).

[image]

The below python code will open the image in your default image viewer in so:
[open a new window to show image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413540/showing-an-image-from-console-in-python)

```
>>> from PIL import Image                                                                                
>>> img = Image.open('test.png')
>>> img.show()
```

Why no new window opened and gimp start to show the image when executing in my os?

Comment: First, make sure you have the image path is correct by replacing its name with its absolute path. Second, try opening images with `matplotlib`.
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
`img = Image.open(path_to_the_image)`
`plt.imshow(image)`
`plt.show()`

Comment: PIL is looking for `eog` or `xv` to view the image with, so try installing either of those packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install matplotlib in Debian run `sudo apt install python3-matplotlib`. Use pyplot from the matplotlib Python module to display the image as follows.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
plt.imshow(Image.open('test.png'))
plt.show()
```

Alternatively install eog with `sudo apt install eog` and your original code will display the image in a new window. Please note that if the image is small then the new window will also be small, and you might not notice that it is open.